# C: Function keeps receiving zeroed out pointer when pointer is actually pointer to something

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I apologize for the confusing title and I hope my explanation will help clear up the fog of confusion that is most likely taking place in your mind right now. So today I decided to try and create a binary tree program that was capable of inserting and searching for certain numbers. Now when I had finished my search function and decided to test it I got a `Segmentation Fault`. I then had the current IDE I was using run GDB to find the root of my problem. GDB then returned with the following message:

```
  Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.                                                             
    0x0000000000400634 in search (num=503, dt=0x0) at main.c:39                                                      
    39          if(num < dt->data) {
```

what I had seem to notice is that for some strange reason my dt(which is a struct which the function uses to navigate threw the binary tree)pointer variable had been zeroed out even though the variable I had entered into the function is pointing to a allocated buffer. This has left me in confusion for quite a while now and hopefully someone can assist me on figuring out the root of this problem.

> My Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define ROOT_NODE 500
typedef struct _DNode {
    int data;
    struct _DNode *right;
    struct _DNode *left;
}Node;
Node *InitNode();
void insert(int num, Node *dt);
int search(int num, Node *dt);

void insert(int num,Node *dt) {
    if(num <= dt->data) {
       if(dt->left == NULL) {
           dt->left = InitNode(num);
       }else {
           insert(num,dt->left);
            }
    }else {

        if(dt->right == NULL) {
            dt->right = InitNode(num);
        }else {
            insert(num,dt->right);
        }
    }
}

int search(int num,Node *dt) {

    if(num < dt->data) {
        if(dt->left == NULL) {
            return -1;
        }else {
           return search(num,dt->left);
        }
    }else {
        if(num > dt->data) {
            if(dt->right == NULL) {
                return -1;
            } else {
                return search(num,dt->left);
            }
        }
        if(num == dt->data) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}

Node *InitNode(int num) {
    Node *TNode = (struct _DNode *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    TNode->right = NULL;
    TNode->left = NULL;
    TNode->data = num;
    return (TNode);
}

int main()
{
     Node *root = InitNode(ROOT_NODE);
     root->data = ROOT_NODE;
     insert(507,root);
     insert(503,root);

     printf("%i",search(503,root));
}
```

Comment: Try "simulating" your code by hand, walking through it carefully, and this should help you find the place where things go wrong.  This is the best way to understand problems like this, and if I were interviewing you for a programming job, that's what I'd ask you to do.

Comment: Copy and paste problem.   After checking `dt->right` is non-NULL, `search(num, dt->left)` is called without checking `dt->left` at all.   If `dt->left` is `NULL`, the recursive call has undefined behaviour, since the first thing it does is access its `data` member.     Probably better to code the functions so they check if `dt` is `NULL` - that way it is safer to call `insert()` and `search()` with ANY pointer.

Comment: Your search function doesn't always return a value, AFAICS (and GCC 7.2.0 agrees with me).  If you're not compiling with lots of compiler warnings, you should be.  And you get undefined behaviour if you ever try to use the value that wasn't returned by `search()`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - I looked at that too.  It's not obvious, but all conditions will enter one of the `if` or `else` clauses, so function won't fall off the end.   I agree, it could be coded to make that more obvious.

Comment: @Peter: Hmmm…yes, it does seem to be 'OK', but I'd not accept code that the compiler is confused about because if the compiler is confused about it,  people reading the code will be confused too.  If the code has tested the cases for greater than and less than, it doesn't need to test for equality; that's all that's left.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - not arguing with that - I'm an advocate of code being as comprehensible as possible for both humans and compilers, and this code fails in that.   However, it isn't the cause of the segmentation fault as asked about   (it's a cause of more difficulty finding the problem, but that's not the same).

Comment: @Peter.: It failed because it was searching always in `left`subtree and then run into NULL.. Well I guess code is a bit messy.

Comment: One thing I would like to make clear is that after the segmentation fault I did implement a `if` statement that checked it `dt` was null and returned `-1` if so. But, this didn't solve the root of my problem because it would have returned `-1` if the number I was searching for was more than `500`. Yes technically this would have been a solution to my problem but just not the "correct" solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Bug!

The problem in your code is you are calling the passing the wrong node in the tree. So it will be

```
return search(num,dt->left);
```

In this place

```
if(dt->right == NULL) {
    return -1;
} else {
    return search(num,dt->left);
                      ^^^^^^
}
```

#### Alternative Implementation

In the code you didn't take advantage of the recursive code. You have repeated same unnecessary code for left and right subtree which shouldn't be the case.

Correct code can be as simple as this

```
    int search(int num,Node *dt) {
        if(dt == NULL)  
             return -1;
        else if(dt->data == num) 
             return 0;
        else if(dt->data >= num) 
             return search(num,dt->left);
        else 
             return search(num,dt->right);
    }
```

Also there is one thing about insertion in your code. You will never in your setup insert a node to an empty tree. And the tree insertion will work correctly only if the `root` is not `NULL`. So the insertion code should be

```
Node * insert(Node *p, int num){
   if(p == NULL)
      return initNode(num);
   else if(num <= p->data)
      return p->left = insert(p->left,num);
   else
      return p->right = insert(p->right,num); 
}
```

And call it like

```
root = insert(root, num);
```

Answer (score 1):

In:

```
            if(dt->right == NULL) {
                return -1;
            } else {
                return search(num,dt->left);
            }
```

you've probably meant:

```
           ...
                return search(num,dt->right);
           ...
```